# ¿Es posible rotar 90 grados un control "Chart" en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Tengo una pequeña gráfica en un form y quisiera saber si es posible girarla 90 grados, de ser asi, podrían mostrarme como lo puediera hacer?

Con este pequeño código puedo dibujar la gráfica.

Dim s As New Series

```
    s.Name = "Ganancia"

    'Change to a line graph.
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    s.BorderWidth = 4

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    s.Points.AddXY("1993", 27)
    s.Points.AddXY("1994", 15)
    s.Points.AddXY("1995", 10)
    s.Points.AddXY("1996", 6)
    s.Points.AddXY("1997", 0)
    s.Points.AddXY("1998", 6)
    s.Points.AddXY("1999", 10)
    s.Points.AddXY("2000", 15)
    s.Points.AddXY("2001", 27)

    Chart1.Series.Add(s)

    With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
        .AxisX.Title = "Año"
        .AxisX.TitleForeColor = Color.MidnightBlue
        .AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 12.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        .AxisX.TitleFont = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 22.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        .AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGreen
        .AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1

        .AxisY.Title = "Ventas"
        .AxisY.TitleForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
        .AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 12.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        .AxisY.TitleFont = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 22.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        .AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightBlue
        .AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 2



        .BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        .BackSecondaryColor = Color.Honeydew
        .BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.HorizontalCenter
        .BorderColor = Color.Black
        .BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
        .BorderWidth = 2
        .ShadowOffset = 5
        .AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90
        .AxisY.LabelStyle.Angle = -90
        s.MarkerStyle = DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Circle
        s.MarkerSize = 7
        s.MarkerColor = Color.Red

        s.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        s.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        s.LabelBackColor = Color.LightPink


    End With

    Chart1.Legends.Clear()
```

[image: Así sería el resultado esperado.]

Les agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: esto es winforms no?

Comment: Así es, la idea es girar sólo el control...

Comment: Nativamente no se puede. Hay algunos controles que te lo permiten como extension del control. pero en winforms, asi simplemente, no se puede. en WPF si se puede.

Comment: ok, entiendo, y alguna estrategia para lograr el fin?, en algún momento intenté ponerlo dentro de un panel y girar el panel pero fue un poco desastroso.

Comment: desconozco. no es algo que venga nativo y no se como se puede hacer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una solución es la siguiente.

Primero, mete los datos invertidos, y los años como enteros en lugar de como `Strings`:

```
s.Points.AddXY(27, 1993)
s.Points.AddXY(15, 1994)
s.Points.AddXY(10, 1995)
s.Points.AddXY(6, 1996)
s.Points.AddXY(0, 1997)
s.Points.AddXY(6, 1998)
s.Points.AddXY(10, 1999)
s.Points.AddXY(15, 2000)
s.Points.AddXY(27, 2001)
```

Luego, inviertes también los ejes:

```
.AxisX.Title = "Ventas"
.AxisX.TitleForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 12.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
.AxisX.TitleFont = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 22.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightBlue
.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 2

.AxisY.Title = "Año"
.AxisY.TitleForeColor = Color.MidnightBlue
.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 12.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
.AxisY.TitleFont = New System.Drawing.Font("TimeBurner", 22.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGreen
.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1
```

Por último, debes poner manualmente los valores máximo, mínimo y el intervalo en el eje Y:

```
AxisY.Maximum = 2001
.AxisY.Minimum = 1993
.AxisY.Interval = 1
.AxisY.IsReversed = True
```

`.AxisY.IsReversed` es para que aparezcan las etiquetas de las ventas arriba en lugar de abajo.

Espero que te sirva. Aqui una captura de como queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente, era lo que buscaba, a partir de aquí se puede realizar lo que se pretendía en un principio, muchas gracias...